# Is this the odd expansion of the function $f(x)=x$ if $0\leq x<1$ and $f(x)=1$ if $1\leq x<2$?

Tags: analysis, fourier-series

We have the function $f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x &, 0\leq x<1 \\ 
1 &, 1\leq x<2 
\end{matrix}\right.$

I want to compute the Fourier sinus series with period 4.

Is the odd expansion of the function the following?

$h(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} 
-1 &, -2<x<-1 \\ 
x& , -1<x<0 \\ 
0 & , x=0,2 \\ 
x &, 0\leq x<1 \\ 
1 &, 1\leq x<2 
\end{matrix}\right.$

The graph of that function is this:

[image]

I think that it is wrong, since a periodic function must be the same for each period. But in this case the line segment $y=x$ is getting higher at each interval. Can that be?

Answer (score 0):

Your extension function $h$ is right, and the extended graph is

[image]

now compute the Fourier series!.

Answer (score 0):

In another way, differentiate $f(x)$ and subtract the continuous component of $1/2$ to get a (odd) square wave, period $2$: suppose you can get easily the sine transform of it.